# How to accesss the fields of set of account id

Tags: apex, soql, set

I have a existing method, passing set of accout id and string into this method.  I want to check a field in the every account record, how can i do this.  Please help

```
public static List<id> test(Set<Id> accs, String ename){

  for(Id accId : accs){
    //here i want to check on a field value on each account say deptname,
  }
}
```

How can i access the field on all account?

Comment: Your questions sounds a bit confusing. Do you intend to fetch a Field Value from Account from the set of IDs, if Yes, then why not use an SOQL to fetch the field data like this: for (Account a : database.query('select Id, Name from Account where ID IN: accs')]{ ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% but I think what you are asking for is something like this

```
public static List test(Set accs, String ename){

     for(Account a : [Select Id, Name, DeptName From Account Where Id In : accs]){
          system.debug(a.DeptName);
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to return the IDs of matching accounts then the database can do that work too:

```
public static List<Id> test(Set<Id> accs, String ename) {
    Map<Id, Account> m = new Map<Id, Account>([
            select Id
            from Account
            where Id in :accs
            and DeptName = :ename
            ]);
    return new List<Id>(m.keySet());
}
```